# Trying to upload CSV for testCase and getting " MultiValueDictKeyError: "'file'""

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload my csv for testing and I keep getting `" MultiValueDictKeyError: "'file'"`  Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
def test_import_existing_order(self):

    data = File(open('TestCSV - OrderTest.csv', 'rb'))
    upload_file = SimpleUploadedFile('data.dump', data.read(),content_type='multipart/form-data')
    request = self.seller_client.put( IMPORT_ORDERS_URL,
        {'file':upload_file,},
            content_type='application/octet-stream',
            content_disposition="attachment; filename=data.dump")

def importOrdersToDict(request):
    import csv
    line_count = 0
    response_data = {"orders":{},
                    "orderCount":0,
                    "dropOffLocations":0,
                    "totalCases":0,
                    "locations":{},
                    }
    csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    csv_file.seek(0)
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

Edit: I tried changing my request to :

```
request = self.seller_client.put( IMPORT_ORDERS_URL,
        {'file':upload_file,},
            # content_type='application/octet-stream',
            format="multipart"
            content_disposition="attachment; filename=data.dump")
```

Which gives me:

```
File "/Users/andynguyen/Documents/AggrigatorCode/aggrigator/aggrigator/views/views_rest.py", line 823, in importOrdersToDict
    csv_file.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
```